# Why did Tissaia de Vries commit suicide?

Tags: character-motivation, the-witcher

Why did Tissaia de Vries commit suicide after the coup on Thanedd Island? That happens as Geralt and Dandelion talk about what happened after the coup. After every part of their conversation there is a sort of flashback on things that happen.

> ‘Not one of the sorcerers changed their mind? Not even when Nilfgaard was beating and burning Aedirn, no one abandoned Vilgefortz
> and joined Philippa?’
>
> ‘No one’
>
> Geralt was silent for a long time.
>
> ‘I don’t believe it,’ he said finally very silently. ‘I don’t believe
> that none would reject Vilgefortz, when his true motives and
> consequences for his betrayal came to light. I am, as is known, a
> naive, stupid, anachronistic witcher. Perhaps that is why I cannot
> believe that none of the mage‘s conscience awakened.’

They discuss whether any of the mages felt any sort of remorse for the happenings in the coup, and then the story goes straight to a flashback where Tissaia slits her wrists.

Why is that? She shouldn't feel any remorse as she was neutral and didn't betray the Brotherhood of Sorcerers. It just doesn't makes sense for her to do such a thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't the flashback to Tissaia in exactly the moment when Geralt said what he said  not the explanation?

But reading on:

> Maid. Ordinary human. Ordinary human with eyes full of fear of what's coming. Ordinary human lost in times of contempt. Ordinary human, seeking hope and tomorrow's surety from her, the sorceress...
>
> Orinary human, whose trust she failed.*

I'd say her conscience awakened.

*Translation from original by the Author of this Answer.

Comment: But how did she failed them, she didn't do anything wrong... She didn't have anything on her conscience..

Comment: She was deceived by Vilgefortz, and when she saw her mistake it was too late. And way she was treated by Vilgefortz in the immediate aftermath didn't help. And yes, she did had a lot on her conscience - she was the one directly responsible for the Thanedd carnage and she was unable to keep magical professions politically independent.